# Indicar pagina inicial, dentro de uma pasta do meu site

Tags: html

Tenho um site, onde criei algumas paginas em html dentro de uma pasta, como posso especificar a **pagina inicial**, uma vez que usuário acessa **a pasta** e a pagina escolhida abra automaticamente?
Tentei por nomenclatura index.html dentro da pasta, não funcionou...

(Lembrando que é dendro de uma pasta, na raiz do servidor quando coloco index.html funciona normalmente!)

Comment: Normalmente ao especificar a pasta do servidor que você quer acessar, exp: "www.teste/pasta1/subpasta" o servidor já redireciona automaticamente para a página que estiver como `index.html // index.php // index.asp`, ai depende da implementação do servidor....

Comment: Entendo, mas no meu casa não esta funcionando, oque posso fazer?

Comment: Depende de qual servidor está utilizando.

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos tu estás usando Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect em PHP
Redirecionamento de páginas em PHP
Para fazer com que o usuário ao acessar um determinado endereço do seu site seja redirecionado para outro endereço, dentro ou fora do seu site, você deverá utilizar o parametro location: da função header(). Abaixo segue um exemplo de uso básico desta função:

Da maneira como esta acima, sempre que o usuário acessar a página que contém o código acima, ele será redirecionado automaticamente para http://www.seusite.com.br/pasta.
O redirecionamento não se restringe a endereços absolutos de sites, sendo que você também pode redirecionar para pastas dentro do seu FTP, ou mesmo arquivos que estão na mesma pasta utilizando um caminho relativo a ela.
Para melhor exemplificar isto, vamos criar um script que irá capturar o endereço pelo qual esta acessado, e redirecionar o usuário para outro conforme este endereço de acesso.

Lembrando que para o script acima funcionar, todas as entradas usadas no script deverão estar criadas no DNS.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria renomear ela para index, no entanto **só irá funcionar se seu site estiver em um servidor apache**, ao contrário disso não.